# Jquery each data object attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

I am trying to create table rows containing data from each attribute from my object response using $.each, however the Id, Purpose, and Amount are coming back undefined. I have tested the response in Fiddler and the data is all being received correctly, the problem just seems to be in the "item" part. Here is my Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://chad-test4.clas.uconn.edu/api/Commitments/GetCommitmentPurposes/2",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success:
        function (response) {
            var purposes = $("#purposes tbody");

            if (response.Success == true) {

                purposes.empty();
                var buttons = '<tr><td><button type="button" class="btn-primary">Save</button>'
                        + '<button type="button" class=".btn-danger">Delete</button></td>'

                var list = response.Data;

                $.each(list, function (i, item) {
                    purposes.append(buttons + '<td><select id=' + item.Id + '>' + item.Purpose + '</select>'
                        + '<td><input type="text" val =' + item.Amount + '/>')
                });
            }
        }
        });
});
```

Comment: Can you also post a snippet from the response?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post a snippet of JSON aswell ?

Basically I believe what you need to do is to access the entries by an identifier:

```
$.each( list.items, function(i, item ) {
```

But posting JSON would clarify if that is true.